# Implementing DCI with ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and Ruby. I'm trying to implement Data-Context-Interaction /aka DCI/ paradigm in Rails 3.2.11 app. I have `User` model which `one-to-many` association with `Topic` model. I'm trying to write a mixin to `User`, but they're not working, please can you offer some debugging help.

My mixing looks like:

```
module Speaker

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :assigned_topics, class_name: 'Topic', foreign_key: 'speaker_id'
  end

  def add_topic(topic)
    topic.speaker = self
    topic.save
  end

  def remove_topic(topic)
    topic.speaker = nil
    topic.save
  end
end
```

When I run below code I get an error:

```
u = User.first
u.extend Speaker
u.assigned_topics
NoMethodError: undefined method `assigned_topics' for #<User:0x00000002f5dca8>
```

Comment: This should work, I can't see anything wrong with what you've posted here.

Comment: You mention DCI but are not using it in the posted code. Is the question to what's missing from a DCI perspective or why the code fails to run as you expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do NOT use the DCI pattern in Rails. At least if you expect to get some traffic. Extending an existing object is currently *terribly slow*. It crashes the caching mechanism of every single ruby implementation.

I know there was some fuzz about this overrated stuff during the last weeks, but really: do not use it this way. It's only a big hassle and much drama around. Rails is *not* a Java framework, and therefore it hasn't the same problems like Java.

If you want to move stuff from models to modules, use a simple concern, and include it hardcoded in the model(s). No live-extend at runtime and all the hoops. Here is a gist from @dhh how to use it: https://gist.github.com/1014971

Comment: DCI does not come from Java. It's based on work from Trygve Reenskauge (farther of MVC) and since he doesn't speak Java it's safe to say it's not from Java (and Java is one of the language with the worst support for it). DCI has nothing to do with #extend either and there are several solutions that work in Ruby (with out performance hits) There is however a lot of misunderstandings of what DCI is.

Comment: Most people just use it with live-extend, though. And i stick to it: it is heavily overrated, unneccessary and adds complexity.

Comment: you should really try and understand the concept before you rate it. DCI _removes_ complexity and gives neccessary tools to seperate what the system is from what it does. That is valuable because those two parts evolve at different speeds. one reason why I dare postulate you haven't understood DCI is that you can do real DCI with live-extend it violates several of the core concepts. I do agree with you that quite a few of the SO CALLED DCI implementations are overly complex and heavy put that has nothing to do with the concept but only to do with misguided tries at implementing it

Comment: DCI in Rails in short: remove logic from activerecord-models, put it into separate roles and therefore modules, and inject it to the objects at runtime as you need it. That said, separation of code is generally reasonable, but the live-injection just adds complexity (depending how you implement it), period. Plain include it in the model classes as a concern and you're done. You may be right from an academical point of view, but what made rails great is pragmatism.

Comment: The pragmatism rails build on was farthered by the same guy who fathered DCI. A safe bet is that true DCI is pragmatic (ps there's no injection in DCI and several solution that has _no_ performance overhead)

Comment: http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3372-put-chubby-models-on-a-diet-with-concerns <-- this is the rails way. Deal with it. And yes, there _is_ injection and there _is_ performance overhead. In a pure MVC/DCI approach, your model doesn't have _any_ logic in it, and everything you need must be injected at runtime _someway_. It may not be the case in C#-stuff, but in Rails _it is_. You could mention the new Ruby 2.0 _refinements_ as a _good enough_ performing solution, but Ruby 2.0 isn't production ready yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22698/discussion-between-hisako-and-rune-fs)

Comment: Thank you guys :). I'm moving my business logic to Domain-Driven-Design /DDD/.

Comment: @Zeck I promised in discussion to get back with information on other approaches this gist https://gist.github.com/4621229 shows an example of an injectionless approach to DCI in Ruby. You can read about the effort at runefs.wordpress.com. I expect it to be far from perfect (to why read the blog :)) but the fact that it works with no per object injection/extention is stands

Comment: @Zeck I did some testing on the code and wasn't at all satisfied with the performance (eventhough it was a lot faster than extending, I've created a new version which can be found at https://github.com/runefs/Moby an it is now just as fast as regular method invocation.